# migrate mvc 4 forms authentication to mvc 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, migration, forms-authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a website witch I wrote with mvc 4 and the built in forms authentication.
I wish to re-write the site with mvc 6 (.NET 4.5.1 / Core 5) but of course keep my current users (and their ability to login to the site with their Roles).

The mvc 6 built in authentication (OAuth 2.0) is different due to the database tables structure.

What is the best way for me to migrate / use my existing database in the new website?

Answer (score 0):

There's no defined migration path that I'm aware of. Your best bet is to setup a new site with Identity, and then come up with an SSIS package or something to migrate the data based on rules you'll have to work out yourself (basically figure out which tables and columns map together).

Comment: Maybe I'll make a migration project and upload it to git. Thank you.